# Installing Pyhdb or Pyodbc for Hana

Tags: python, pyodbc, hana

I want to connect Python(Anaconda) with my HANA database. I am trying to install the pyhdb connector for HANA. Even tried Pyodbc.

But I am getting the same following error for both

```
SFOM00618927A:~ i854319$ pip install pyhdb
Collecting pyhdb
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x104467fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/pyhdb/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x104467810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/pyhdb/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x104467ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/pyhdb/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x104467ed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/pyhdb/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x104467550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/pyhdb/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyhdb
```

Similar error is there for Pyodbc too. I have the HANA installed and also have Anaconda installed.

Comment: What version of Python and PIP are you using? This may be a problem with the `requests` package: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1805 Have you tried a `pip install --upgrade pip` and then try installing pyhdb or pyodbc with the new pip?

Answer (score 1):

You can hit this error if you're behind a proxy server.

Check out the [Pip proxy argument](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server) if that could be your issue too.

```
pip install pyhdb --proxy [user:passwd@](proxy server):(port)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following fork: https://github.com/hpi-epic/PyHDB

For PIP: `pip install git+git://github.com/hpi-epic/PyHDB`

This fork has all the open issues fixed plus some additional advances.